# __FILE__ returns only filename in Apple's clang

Tags: c++, c, xcode, clang

Preprocessor of clang that gets shipped with Xcode replaces **FILE** only with the filename

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "__FILE__: " << __FILE__ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -o test; ./test
  __FILE__: test.cpp .    <--- I expected the absolute path
```

Isn't **FILE** supposed to get replaced with the absolute path?

```
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I think it expands into "the path and filename that the compiler used to open the file". Try sticking the source file in a directory *other than the current working directory* and then build/run. I think the string may change (in other words, something like `cat > foo.cpp && cd some_dir && g++ (...) ../foo.cpp`, or whatever the equivalent clang command is.

Comment: `__FILE__` is expands to _The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal)._ There's also a note that _The presumed source file name and line number can be changed by the `#line` directive._ Hopefully nobody is "evil" enough to manipulate `#line` directives.

Comment: In other words, it's not necessarily the full path at all. You could have `foo/a.cpp` and `bar/a.cpp`, and `__FILE__` could legally be `"a.cpp"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any chance though to control it if it's absolute or relative?Let's say for clang?